# How can I increase size icon of the legend

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to increase size icon of the legend only. I need help.
My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2183/

```
 legend: {                    
                itemStyle: {
                 fontSize:'20px',
                 font: '20pt Helvetica Neue'
              },
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your CSS

```
.highcharts-legend .fa {
    font-size: 45px;
}
```